# beautiful soup, eliminating certain items with Findall()

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a series of list items being returned by find_all()

```
<li class="rsltItem" mh-property-list-item="".......
```

The item has lots of nested elements.

Every so often, one of the li is slightly different:

```
<li class="rsltItem adv" in-view="vm.lazyLoadAd('adMiddle',$inview)" ng-if="$index == 5"><!----></li>
```

This one has fewer, different nested elements. I want to eliminate the second type.

I have tried searching on the specific class for the li, but even though they are different, it returns them all:

```
soup.find_all("li", {"class" : "rsltItem"})
```

Any ideas how i can exclude the 2nd list item from my results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result_list = [tag for tag in soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'rsltItem'}) 
if tag['class'] == ['rsltItem']]
```

or

```
result_list = [tag for tag in soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'rsltItem'}) 
if len(tag['class']) == 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

To find only the tags `<li>` that match a specific class `rsltItem`,

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'li' and tag.get('class') == ['rsltItem'])
```